# Jetty 9.4 Unreadable Session

Tags: java, spring, jetty

We are upgrading our Jetty from 9.3.x to 9.4.x, and are running into an issue with session clustering.

When the server tries to load a session, it tries to unmarshal objects stored in the attributes of the sessions. It fails to load the relevant classes of these objects. The classloader of the SessionManager does not appear to have access to the classpath in the deployed WAR itself.

We deploy to jetty using a separate jetty-base. Our WebAppContext looks like this:

```
<Configure id="support-server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
  <Set name="contextPath">/</Set>
  <Set name="war"><Property name="jetty.base" default="."/>/support-server.war</Set>
  <Set name="extraClasspath"><Property name="jetty.base" default="."/>/config</Set>
  <Set name="defaultsDescriptor"><Property name="jetty.base" default="."/>/etc/webdefault.xml</Set>
  <Set name="tempDirectory">tmp</Set>
  <Set name="maxFormKeys">10000</Set>
  <Set name="maxFormContentSize">2000000</Set> 
</Configure>
```

Deploying and starting the webapp by using the start.jar in the jetty-home works. The app can be used as it should. But when we restart the server and the session is loaded from storage, it throws an UnreadableSessionDataException.

We've tried session storage based on Google Cloud Datastore, and on MongoDB, but both end up with the same issue. Looking into the code on github (https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.14.v20181114/jetty-gcloud/jetty-gcloud-session-manager/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/gcloud/session/GCloudSessionDataStore.java) shows the mechanism used is the same:

```
try (ClassLoadingObjectInputStream ois = new ClassLoadingObjectInputStream(blob.asInputStream()))
{
    SessionData.deserializeAttributes(session, ois);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    throw new UnreadableSessionDataException (id, _context, e);
}
```

The details of the stack-trace are:

```
Caused by: 
org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.UnreadableSessionDataException: 
Unreadable session developmentsplje48spmp5vzaujq3ydjga0 for development__0.0.0.0
  at org.eclipse.jetty.gcloud.session.GCloudSessionDataStore.sessionFromEntity(GCloudSessionDataStore.java:944)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.gcloud.session.GCloudSessionDataStore.doLoad(GCloudSessionDataStore.java:509)
... 30 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
com.fleetnology.support.web.overview.mo.TicketOverviewTableMo
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
  at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:683)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.ClassLoadingObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ClassLoadingObjectInputStream.java:93)
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1863)
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1746)
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2037)
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1568)
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:428)
  at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1409)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
  at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1158)
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2173)
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2064)
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1568)
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:428)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.ClassLoadingObjectInputStream.readObject(ClassLoadingObjectInputStream.java:70)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionData.deserializeAttributes(SessionData.java:126)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.gcloud.session.GCloudSessionDataStore.sessionFromEntity(GCloudSessionDataStore.java:940)
... 31 more
```

The implementation of the SessionManager in 9.3.X did not use the ClassLoadingObjectInputStream and did not cause any issues.

Most questions and solutions here are related to the inverse, classes in the WAR not being able to use Jetty Server classes.
The documentation about ClassLoading in Jetty seems to be focussed on acces from within the webapp to classes of the Jetty Server.